# Multiple recipient's Mail with attachment

Tags: sql-server

In sql server 2012 I have to send mail to multiple recipients with an attachment. The recipient has unique Id_no. and attachment file is saved according to that id_no. Hence matching to that id_no. the attachment has to be sent.

Can anyone help me with query?

Answer (score 0):

An email has recipients and attachments that are not related
All recipients get all attachments

If you need to match one attachment to one recipient, send one email per recipient

Answer (score 0):

In the case you know the id of the recipients and the information about the Id and the attachment path is stored in a table you can compose an attachment path based on that and add it to the email like:

```
DECLARE @AttchPath NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @AttachPath = COALESCE(@AttachPath + ';','') +  <column_path> 
FROM <attachments_table> 
WHERE Id_no IN (SELECT Id_no FROM <recipients_table>)
```

Use `@AttachPath` to send the email.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks!! Yes there is a table which has multiple recipient's email_id and recipient_id respectively.

Comment: You`re welcome, don't forget to mark it as an answer if it helped you!